# Power Query - Data after combing not showing in the same order

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Power Query to combine 3 Excel 3 sheets inside 1 workbook and something very weird happening!

So for example i have the "Queue" - "Date" columns as the 1st and 2nd columns for the 3 sheets, but when i combine them using new blank query the the "Queue" and "Date" changes as 2nd and 1st!!!!!!! thats just after importing the sheets which means there is no codes or steps are being used to do this change!!!

example

```
Agent   Queue       CC  AHT
Sarah   KLNLA-21    12  65
Kim     KLNLA-22    33  78
Dan     KLNLA-23    43  91
Shila   KLNLA-24    66  104
```

After combining

```
Agent   Queue      CC      AHT
Sarah   12         KLNLA-21 65
Kim     33         KLNLA-22 78
Dan     43         KLNLA-23 91
Shila   66         KLNLA-24 104
```

I noticed that if i import same data which is same structure but from new source as Excel sheet the data comes up same as the sources data with no issues.

Edit: here is the code from the advanced editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "Query1")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"1-Aug", "Sarah", "Column1", "Column2", "Kim", "Column3", "Column4", "Dan", "Column5", "Column6", "Queue Level", "1-Sep"}, {"1-Aug", "Sarah", "Column1", "Column2", "Kim", "Column3", "Column4", "Dan", "Column5", "Column6", "Queue Level", "1-Sep"})
in
    #"Expanded Content"
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Edit your question and for each query involved, post the code from home...advanced editor...   within powerquery

Comment: You need to check your table structures. You will find they are not identical between sources from the untouched new source compared to the table before the expand step

Comment: the problem is when i add the data in another excel sheet and use PQ to combine it shows up in same order with no issues, but using PQ within the same sheet it shows that issue, thats why im being confused now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it fixed, actually the raw data table had some issue due to some cells are being merged in untidy way.